# Empty space inside regular expression java

Tags: java, regex, space

I'm trying to validate a phone number. The format is (xx) xxxxx-xxxx.
It was working when I was ignoring the space after the (xx). I was using this expression:

```
return telefone.matches("\\(([10]|[1-9][0-9])\\)\\d{5}-\\d{4}");
```

I tried to add a simple space after '\\)', but it didn't work. I also tried using '\\s' but it also doesn't work. Can someone help me?

Comment: Sounds like you need to trim() the string first.

Answer (score 2):

use `\s` to match whitespace characters:

```
return telefone.matches("\\(\\d{2}\\)\\s+\\d{5}-\\d{4}");
```

Comment: Omg, I'm SO stupid!

I created a main method just to test different expressions faster, typing the values in a loop, and I just noticed I was using the Scanner.next() method, not nextLine(), that's why it wasn't working with the space.

Thank you for replying, it made the double test the expression in the real code and it worked fine! :)